# How to use a java package on a asp.net site

Tags: java, .net

My Bank has givien me the option of using a COM component, Java (JAR) package or a plain C dll to interface with thier payment gateway.

Given that I'd rather chew my arm off before installing their COM component on my server (Which I've spent the last 5 years eradicating of asp and com components) I'd like to host/convert the Java package in/to asp.net (version 2.0, but can be 3.5 if there's any magic dust to help the job)

I can decompile the .class files fine and was going to start re-coding the suff in C# when I thought I'd have a look and see if theres anything that will do the grunt work to save me a few hours?

I've seen something called the Java Language Conversion Assistant, which I dont have an option for in my VStudio 2008 Std installer, so am looking for my old 2005 disks.

I've also found reference to a few tools shipped with j#, namely JbImp.exe and vjc.exe which can be used to host/cross compile java into IL.

Does anyone have any experience of using any of these options? (or any suggestions other than "get of your lazy **** and do it yourself" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IKVM allows you to use Java classes in .NET : http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: Hey, thats more like it! Not quite what I was after but probably workable all the same.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at JNBridge - http://www.jnbridge.com/

Comment: Good answer, and if it was a large and complex java package then hosting a JVM might be the best solution, however for this little package I am looknig to convert it to IL and host it in asp.net (to maintain the xcopy deployment)